# Include dgles in Xcode project

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, xcode4

I am trying to port an app that has OpenGL-ES code to work on the Mac with OpenGL only. After some research I have found a wrapper for OpenGL-ES to convert the code into OpenGL commands in dales. The only problem I am having a hard time figuring out how to import the code into Xcode 4, there are none of the 'framework' folders that I am used to. Does any one have any experience on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1) from apple's documentation